# The configured wait value is not used when I get resource

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I open web page (by link) I using WebDriverWait to make shure the page completely opened. There I set 30 seconds to wait before error arises.

```
try {
    driver.get(link);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(webDriver ->
    (js).executeScript("return document.readyState;").equals("complete"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("ERROR_31");
    logger.info(e.toString());
    return;
}
```

Newetherless when the error comes the output in logs are

```
ERROR_31
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Navigation timed out after 5000 ms
```

And it looks like that 30 second delay is not used. Instead, the webdriver default of 5 seconds is used. What's the mistake here?

Comment: it will only wait as long as it takes for the condition to be met, or the timeout period is reached.  You won't need this, though, Selenium will automatically wait after using a .get().

Comment: @pcalkins "Selenium will automatically wait after using a .get()" - will wait for what condition? Without any wait for page load I often got `Navigation timed out`

Comment: It'll wait for the page to load.  This depends on how PageLoadStrategy is set, but default is to wait for readyState of "Complete".  (Page returned and outside resources loaded...)  It won't wait for "lazy loaded" objects, though.

Comment: @pcalkins "It won't wait for "lazy loaded" objects, though." maybe it's the point?

Comment: dunno, but checking readyState won't be very reliable. (You don't know when the code will fire in relation to the ready state which can be in flux...)  Better to use a webdriverwait with explicit condition if you are waiting for lazy loaded elements.